# Merging some revisions but not others with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, merge, branch

I recently started tracking changes for my project with Mercurial. I made several revisions before I started working on a certain feature. Now, I want to go back to my revision before I implemented that feature and try implementing it a very different way. However, I want to keep some of the changes I made while working on the first implementation because they apply equally no matter what implementation I choose.

What's the best way to update back to the revision before I started implementing the feature, but selectively incorporate changes along the default branch into a new, separate branch? Is this the right way to merge/branch with Mercurial? If I do this, can I later "drop" one of those branches in favor of one particular implementation of this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very easy if you have an external diff program like Beyond Compare.

1. Enable the [extdiff](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) extension and configure it to use your diff program (e.g. I have my system set up so that `hg bcompare` will run Beyond Compare)
2. Update your repo's working directory to the revision where you want to start the new branch.
3. Use Mercurial to run your diff program against the head with the experimental changes.
4. Cherry pick the changes you want from the experimental code, either whole files or smaller diffs within files.
5. When you exit your diff program, your working directory will have the changes you picked.
6. Start a new branch (`hg branch`) or set a bookmark (`hg bookmark`) to track this new set of changes against.  See http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/ for a description of the differences.
7. Commit the changes, and off you go!

When you decide which implementation you want, you can either update to the head of the branch you **don't** want and use `hg commit --close-branch` to mark it as closed, which still leaves it as a head in the repository.  If you want to remove it as a head,  update to the head of the branch you **do** want and use `hg merge --tool internal:local <rev-of-the-other-head>` to merge it, but keep all the wanted changes.

Comment: Thanks for that! Won't those changes seemingly come out of nowhere if I follow that procedure, though? That is, if I follow those steps, how will someone else looking at the revision history know which intermediate revisions I pulled changes from?

Comment: That's right; in that case I would put a note to that effect in the commit message -- along the lines of "these are handpicked changes from revs X through Y so I can try a different implementation".  If changes you want are isolated to particular changeset or sets, you could use `hg backout` to remove the changesets you don't want.  Or if they're isolated to particular files, `hg revert` will let you pick the files where you want to go back to the original version and keep working with the changes you do.

Comment: I tried your original procedure, and it certainly worked, but it feels messy to me. I think using `backout` might work if I understood it better. My complaint about messiness is because my revision graph doesn't show the intermediate changes actually merging into the new branch, which is what's happening. (Some changesets have changes where I want to pick and choose what I merge, but I should be able to handle that anyway.) Is there no way to achieve this so the revision history more accurately reflects what I've done to the repository?

Comment: @Henry: would the revers of my procedure work? Update to the tip of the experimental branch, do a diff against the start of that work and cherry pick the changes you want to keep, then commit with a message "remove unwanted parts of implementation #1; start on implementation #2".

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old, but I ran into something similar today when working on a project. I had spent a few days going down a dead-end trying out a feature on the default branch. Here's the process I used to get my code base back in a good condition.

1. I updated back to the last good revision (in my case, R0!) via
   *hg update -R 0*
2. I created a new branch for the feature (*hg branch NEWFEATURE* and *hg commit*)
3. I started cherry-picking good
   commits from the other branch via tranplant (*hg transplant -b
   default revNumberToPick*)

Transplant is shipping in the box with mercurial now, and just requires you to enable it. The documentation is located on [Mercurial wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TransplantExtension). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this sometime. I've been using Git for my projects lately, but I still have this Mercurial repo. Believe it or not, this particular issue (and my other shortcomings with DVCS) frustrated me enough to give up on this project!

Comment: I've been motivationally thwarted from many projects for far less than that